# Running multiple stored procedures with one SqlDataAdapter

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sqldataadapter

My question: is there any way to run multiple stored procedures with one `SqlDataAdapter` like this

```
adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("ProcforselectUserTableWhere ; ProcforselectuserTypeAuthorizationWhere", con);
adapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Userid", Request.QueryString[0]);  
adapter.Fill(dataset);
```

I tried this but I am getting the error:

> Could not find stored procedure 'ProcforselectUserTableWhere ; ProcforselectuserTypeAuthorizationWhere'.

Please help

Comment: You'll need to make it into a SQL Command instead with multiple EXEC's and then add your own explicit parameters.  Or else write a stored procedure to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible because stored procedures are executed differently than raw SQL statements. See, the parameters are implied with stored procedures, not defined in the query. Therefore the `Fill` method is looking for a stored procedure that is literally named in the `CommandText`.